# Regular expression for pattern xxxx/xxxxU

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I'm looking for a regular expression to match the pattern xxxx/xxxxU, where x can be 0-9 and the "U" at the end is optional.

Valid examples: 1111/1111, 1111/1111U
Invalid examples: 1111/1111Z, 111/1111

I could reach until '[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{4}', but I'm not sure how to handle the optional "U" at the end.

Comment: I tried '[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{4}U?', it does not work. 1111/1111/D1 is valid with this. BTW, I'm using this with oracle regexp_like() but I guess all regular expression should work here as well.

Comment: You can add a `$` to the end to indicate that it should be the end of the string; the first part of your example *does match*.

Comment: If the string matches the number-slash-number format but ends in a letter other than U, should just the numbers and slash part match or should nothing match?

Answer (score 2):

#### Always match numbers-slash-numbers; U included, if present:

```
[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{4}U?
```

or if you replace the number ranges with \d (for a digit character):

```
\d{4}/\d{4}U?
```

The `?` means zero or one of the preceding character. So zero or one of `U`. [Test it](http://regex101.com/r/fB7iO8/5)

The entire string 1111\2222U will be matched, while the match for 1111\2222Z will include the digits-slash-digits part but not the Z.

#### Only match if string ends in a digit or U:

If a string fragment ending in any letter other than U is not to be matched at all, try something like:

```
^\d{4}/\d{4}U?$
```

which matches if the numbers-slash-numbers plus optional U is the only content in the string ([test it](http://regex101.com/r/fB7iO8/6)) or

```
\d{4}/\d{4}U?(\s|$)
```

which matches if the numbers-slash-numbers plus optional U is followed by either a white space character (included in the match) or the end of the string. ([Test it](http://regex101.com/r/fB7iO8/6).)

(Note: the *test it* links show the "/" between the numbers escaped with "\" [e.g. "/"]--something required by that implementation. I'm not familiar with Oracle's regex syntax, so this may  not be required on that platform.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use '[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{4}U?' or '[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{4}U{0,1}'

Found at: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_re.htm

Answer (score 1):

You could try this expression:

```
 [0-9]{4}/[0-9]{4}U?
```

The `?` means: optional (0 or 1). Have a look at [**this**](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=regex)  useful regex overview table.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your comments, but there were some cases which your answer did not cover.

'^[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{4}U?$'

The above works for all of my above cases